# Limit the number of rows in a multiline textbox

Tags: asp.net, .net, regex, textbox, multiline

Is there a way to limit the number of rows in a multiline textbox?  I only want to allow a user to input up to 12 lines of text in a multiline textbox.  Right now the textbox accepts as many lines as a user throws at it.

Another hurdle is the fact that the multiline textbox is inside of a listview making it difficult to retrieve the Textbox name using JavaScript.

Can I simply use a regular expression validator to limit the number of new lines to 12?  If so, what would be the proper Regex?  I've tried `^(\n|\r|\r\n){0,12}$` but it doesn't work at all.

Comment: @driis: I assume(and have edited) ASP.NET since he mentioned the `RegularExpressionValidator`.

Comment: @user1588026: Why do you want to limit the lines at all? Lines are normally just a formatting issue, they are not related to the size of the string. You can set the `Rows` property but that doesn't prevent to enter more lines, it just limits the visible height of the textbox. Of course you can use javacript and serverside code to detect the `NewLines`. But is it really worth the effort? You have to detect them first, it could be `\r\n`or `\n` or `<br />` or `<br>` etc. But that could also be part of the text.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter:  The reason I need to limit it, is that the input will be used to populate a field in an existing PDF document.  Only 12 rows of text will fit in the PDF document's text field (it's a fixed size) and only 65 characters per row will fit.

Comment: @user1588026: So even if you would limit the lines you could exceed the 65 char limit. Maybe it's possible to shorten the the text a little bit. Btw, does the pdf text field wrap the text automatically when it's too large for it?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: Yes, the PDF text field will automatically wrap the text when it is too large (works similar to the multiline textbox with wrap = true.  The max the pdf field can handle is 12 rows of 65 characters.  I need to somehow figure out how to automatically add a newline when the 65th character is reached, but I wouldn't want to cut a word in half.  This is begining to sound more and more unreasonable.  Maybe I should just place 12 individaul textbox's on the page with a maxlength of 65 each and then combine them all on the server side.  Ugh....this will be ugly for the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use a regex validator for this. Try this expression:

```
^[^\n]*(?:\n[^\n]*){0,11}$
```

If you also want to limit the lines to a maximum of 65 character each, you can use:

```
^[^\n]{0,65}(?:\n[^\n]{0,65}){0,11}$
```

If you want to count the lines as if there are soft line breaks for lines longer than 65 characters, this could work:

```
^[^\n]{0,65}(?:\n?[^\n]{0,65}){0,11}$
```

Note the `?` after the `\n`, making the line break character it self optional.

You may want to optimize this expression to minimize backtracking by adding atomic groups, for example:

```
^(?>[^\n]{0,65})(?>(?>\n?[^\n]{0,65}){0,11})$
```

Comment: Thank you, I tested your solution and it definately limits the input to 11 carriage returns, however as Tim pointed out I can have one line that spans more than 65 characters and it gets wrapped to the next line, efectivley making up several rows without a /n.

Comment: Absolutely amazing!  Your last 2 expressions do exactly what I hoped for.  The only downside is that depending on the characters typed, a line can actually hold more than 65 characters due to the different character widths.  I think I'm just going to have to switch to a monospace font such as courier so that all of the lines look OK.  It would look wierd if one row was 1/3 longer then the next due to the characters used.  Thank you so much.